# Analyzing Google form submissions based on timestamps dynamically

Tags: google-sheets

I am able to Query my data by the date in a timestamp

```
=COUNT(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$E, "Select A where A>=date '"&TEXT(B$5,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(B$6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

but now I want to narrow it down to the hour and the day

I am attempting to build a grid of when my responses come in by date and time over the hour.
Date ranges have to be dynamic.  I would like to go look at a sample of data over a week or a sample of data over a year.

How can I add a conditional time statement to this.   The time and day statement does not need to be dynamic because they will always remain the same.

And then how can I filter what day the timestamp was created on in the query.

This is what I want to do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(hour(Sheet2!$A:$A),HOUR($A2),Sheet2!$A:$A,">"&0,WEEKDAY(Sheet2!$A:$A,2),B$1))
```

Copy it right and down the range. Need to have weekdays numbers in Row 1. [Look at example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C1fqwvlIqcYPJT0RfnCyMel-La5290vZ6QDbLKT2upU/edit?usp=sharing).